# Is there a way to correctly suppress an F# Type Constraint Warning?

Tags: f#

I have a Type Constraint by design Explicitly defined for a set of functions that I intend to use Types with a corresponding List/Collection type. Even though I actually define the constraint it still gives me a warning that I cannot remove.  This isn't critical, but I really so heavily on working through all the warnings and not being able to clear the list is a little annoying.

```
let domainValue (domain:'Domain when 'Domain :> 'ItemDomain list) //Address Type Constraint Warning ?
            : Value<'ItemDomain,'Domain> = (domain, (domain |> validDomainResult |> Some)) ||> value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constraint is saying that the argument should be a type `'Domain` such that `'Domain :> list<'ItemDomain>`, i.e. a type that has `list<'ItemDomain>` as a base class.

However, `list<'T>` is a sealed class and so there can be no type other than `list<'ItemDomain>` that would satisfy the constraint - the only type that satisfies the constraint is `list<'ItemDomain>` and so you could as well simplify the type declaration and use:

```
let domainValue (domain:list<'ItemDomain>) = ...
```

It is worth noting that this is not the case for interfaces like `seq<'T>` and so the following gives no error:

```
let domainValue (domain:'Domain when 'Domain :> seq<'ItemDomain>) = ...
```

This will allow arguments that are any kind of collection of `'ItemDomain` values including arrays, lists, etc. Also, you can write the same constraint more concisely using `#` type, which means the same thing:

```
let domainValue (domain:#seq<'ItemDomain>) = ...
```